# Is there an easy way to raise or lower the hat operator in math mode

Tags: beamer, math-mode, accents

Using the hat operator in math mode in beamer, the hats are smashing into the characters.  I can use `\skew{n}` to move them n points to the right, but I need to raise them a point or two.  Is there an easy way to do this?

For example, the identity operator:

```
\[ \skew{4} \hat{\textrm{\emph{I}} \]
```

ends up looking like an anemic lollipop.  (I use an italicized text mode I because in the math font, the capitol I is a angled straight line that could easily be a 1 or a lowercase l.)

Any advice?

Regards,
Martin

Comment: 1. No easy way. 2. You should use another math font instead of use a text font in math mode.

Comment: You may need actually `\usefonttheme{serif}` or `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can raise them with the help of an invisible rule:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \[\skew{4} \hat{\textrm{\emph{\rule{0ex}{1.7ex}I}}}\]
    \[\skew{4} \hat{\textrm{\emph{\rule{0ex}{2ex}I}}}\]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To lower them, you need to `\smash` the variable `I` and adjust the height of the rule:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \[\skew{4} \hat{\textrm{\emph{\rule{0ex}{1.5ex}\smash{I}}}}\]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]